# how to set node path in at /usr/local/bin using nvm

Tags: path, symlink

I have installed node using nvm first time and now when I run

`which node` in terminal it gives me

*/Users/username/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.4/bin/node*

but what I need that node path must be  at */usr/local/bin/node*

Do I need to uninstall nvm and install via brew so that it will set the node to correct location?

or how to set correct path?

Comment: If you are using nvm then you want it on your PATH so you can switch versions of node